# how can i sum rows that share a similar term

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to edit my query below, so that it combines rows that share a similar term (i.e. Love/ like/ dislike) together
Current query & results

```
SELECT values,
count(distinct uuid) as count
FROM
  `response_values` AS rv
left JOIN
  `responses_comprehensive` AS r
ON
  r.question_id=rv.qid
WHERE
  question_wording="campaign rating" and values not like '%missing%'

GROUP BY
 values
```

output:

| values | count |
| --- | --- |
| love it | 5 |
| love itlove it | 1 |
| hate it | 50 |
| hate ithate it | 10 |
| neutral | 2 |
| neutral neutral | 2 |

**DESIRED TABLE OUTPUT**

| values | count |
| --- | --- |
| love it | 6 |
| hate it | 60 |
| neutral | 4 |

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm whether your issue is resolved or not. If not, can you provide your sample data which you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to create categories for each end value in order to group the data later on.

To build those categories, a CASE statement combined with the LIKE operator will be enough.

I would add a new column to the "response_values" table with the category.

This will allow you to retain the original response and add the category to perform aggregations later on.

This query will solve the question:

```
SELECT curated_values,
count(distinct uuid) as count
FROM
  (SELECT *, CASE WHEN LOWER(term) LIKE '%love%' THEN "LOVE IT"
     WHEN LOWER(term) LIKE '%hate%' THEN "HATE IT"
     WHEN LOWER(term) LIKE '%neutral%' THEN "NEUTRAL"
     ELSE "UNKNOWN" END AS curated_values FROM `response_values`) AS rv
left JOIN
  `responses_comprehensive` AS r
ON
  r.question_id=rv.qid
WHERE
  question_wording="campaign rating" and values not like '%missing%'

GROUP BY
 curated_values
```

You can adjust the CASE clauses to your needs. I have added a LOWER function, for example, to catch all case variations.